# Smooth sensor data like in the cardboard app

Tags: java, android, sensors, android-sensors, virtual-reality

I am wondering how the google cardboard (and all the other vr apps for android) manage to get an exact rotation angle of the device. The app follows my head very fast and precise. I already read about low-pass filtering and sensor fusion. But is this the way how vr apps collect the sensor data?

If not, could you give an example code on how to get sensor data like cardboard apps in my own **non-cardboard** app?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few places that I have seen people make this open source or tried to decompile the hardware.  I would just leave it as a comment, but rep is too low.

[This is some open source code that replicates cardboard.](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Hardware/accelerometer/com_google_vrtoolkit_cardboard_sensorsHeadTracker_java.htm)

[And there are some people who have tried to decompile it](https://github.com/Zomega/Cardboard/blob/master/src/com/google/vrtoolkit/cardboard/sensors/HeadTracker.java)

Good luck!

Comment: First of all: Thank you for your answer - I upvoted it. It looks interesting. I would be happy if I could use some of this code to build my own very accurate orientation sensor.